# Return a List of Results from an API Call

Tags: c#, wpf, api, xaml, asynchronous

I am creating an app that calls a recipe API with user-selected parameters and then returns a List of results. However, I am having trouble returning more than one result.
Here is the code I have:

```
//this is the recipe model
public class RecipeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}


//this is the Result model 
//I had to make a model of a model because the result is a nested JSON response
public class RecipeResultModel
{
    public List<RecipeModel> Results { get; set; }
}

//this is the method of making the API call
public static async Task<List<RecipeModel>> LoadRecipes(string queryString)
{
    var url = $"{ queryString }";

    using (var response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            RecipeResultModel result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RecipeResultModel>();

            return result.Results;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);               
        }
    }
}

//here is method that displays the Recipe results
///EDITED CODE

private BindingList<RecipeResultModel> _results;
public BindingList<RecipeResultModel> Results
        {
            get
            {
                return _results;
            }
            set
            {
                _results = value;
                
            }
        }

private async Task<List<RecipeResultModel>> ShowResults()
{
      var recipeList = _mapper.Map<List<RecipeResultModel>>(recipeInfo);
                ResultList = new BindingList<RecipeResultModel>(recipeList);
                ResultList.ItemsSource = recipeList;
}
```

I can successfully get a single result back from ShowResults(), however I am needing a List.

Comment: *"I can successfully get a single result back from ShowResults(), however I am needing a List."* -- Could you elaborate on this? As far as I can see the `ShowResults` returns a naked `Task`. It doesn't propagate any specific results.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `Task` on `ShowResults()' means that the function only returns the state of the task -- if it finished or not.

If you want to get a list back from an async Function, you need to add the type you want back after the `Task` in the function definition, like you did on the static `LoadRecipes` method.

```cs
private async Task<List<TheTypeIWant>> ShowResults()
{
    var recipeInfo = await RecipeProcessor.LoadRecipes(RecipeUrl);

    /*create a list of recipes*/

    foreach (var recipe in recipeInfo)
    {
        var uriSource = new Uri(recipe.Image, UriKind.Absolute);
        recipeResult.Text = recipe.Title;

        /*add the recipe to the list*/     
    }

    return /*return the list of recipes*/;
}
```

You need to replace the stuff in comments with the appropriate types for whatever you're trying to do. It's not clear from the question.

You could just return RecipeResults from the static LoadResults() function and the ShowResults() Function

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

When you have a response from an Aysnc/Await call you need to specify the `.Result` at the end.

See this `.Result` at the end of the await call:

```
RecipeResultModel result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RecipeResultModel>().Result;
return result.Results;
```

## Tip

Given the keyword go ahead and refactor your code not to use the word `.Results`.

```
public class RecipeResultModel
{
    public List<RecipeModel> Recipes { get; set; }
}


RecipeResultModel result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<RecipeResultModel>().Result;
return result.Recipes;
```

Comment: @JohnV thanks, I thought this was ASP.Net then saw the Xaml tag indicating WPF.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask why the need to use the .Result property. The await is going to unwrap the ReadAsAsync result afaik. The only time you *need* to use the . Result is if it is a property on the Task's returned type, or you're doing more advanced task operations (when.all, etc) and you call .Result on the task itself.

Comment: Now I'm interested in the Exception, @JasonMcGouldrick could you please [edit] your question and include the error - you say *a single result back from ShowResults() works* well what happens with multiple results? I guessed it was `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RecipeResultModel>' to RecipeResultModel` @JohnV do you know why the OP is trying to bind a list of Recipes to the same controls in the ShowResults()? Should these be Business Object Properties the Xaml controls bind to?

Comment: I have the code edited in the question @JeremyThompson now I have one issue. It is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<RecipeResultModel> to 'System.Windows.Controls.Lisitbox' " I am trying to make the results populate a Listbox..